# My emails on a company email account that I no longer work for

Tags: email

To whom do these emails belong and does the company have to grant me the right to have access to them?

Comment: Location?  Can matter.

Comment: You no longer work for the company, and the emails were sent to yourname@companyname.com?

Comment: This seems like an x-y problem. Why do you want the emails? If you expect the company to give them to you, you'd better have a good reason that doesn't involve poaching clients or otherwise taking potential income away from them.

Answer (score 10):

Generally if it's a company email account they own all content and should have at the very least changed the password after you left if not reassigned the email account to someone else.

You have no exclusive rights to any of the content, you would need to ask them. If they haven't changed the password you may still be able to access them, but you would be entering a grey area legally at best.